# Is there a method to not UPDATE row by row and go faster on a table MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where every day I get a new price, so I have to UPDATE the prices in the row and switch them by position: I put the new value in Today_price. The previous value in Today price is put in One_day_ago, the previous One_day_ago is put in Two_day_ago and so on, discarding the last value.
I will have 100'000 different cards, so there will be 100'000 rows in the table.
I cannot run an Update for each row because it will take 3 hours. How can I do to solve the problem?

[image: Example of the table]

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `history_v2` (
  `Idcard` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Min_price` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Today_price` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `One_day_ago` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Two_day_ago` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Three_day_ago` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Four_day_ago` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Five_day_ago` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Six_day_ago` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Seven_day_ago` double(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `Idcollection` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `history_v2` (`Idcard`, `Min_price`, `Today_price`, `One_day_ago`, `Two_day_ago`, `Three_day_ago`, `Four_day_ago`, `Five_day_ago`, `Six_day_ago`, `Seven_day_ago`, `Idcollection`) VALUES
(1, 2.10, 5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 1);
```

Comment: Do the `UPDATE` with no `WHERE` clause and it will update all the rows.

Comment: Sorry but there is a big mess in the table design. Think about normalization instead of one_day_ago, two_days_ago etc. What you need is a pricing history.. Doing so you wouldn't need any updates at all

Comment: If I wanted to go there, I wouldn't start from here :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to design the tables you need is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE history_v2 (
    Idcard int(11) NOT NULL,
    Idcollection int(2) NOT NULL,
    Min_price double(16,2) NOT NULL,
    Min_price_date datetime NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE price_history (
    Idcard int(11) NOT NULL,
    Idcollection int(2) NOT NULL,
    price double(16,2) NOT NULL,
    price_date datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Then doing always an INSERT INTO `price_history` and, in the approach I imagined, updating `Min_price` and `Min_price_date` on table `history_v2` if, once inserted the new value in `price_history` there is a record in `history_v2` with the same `Idcard` and `Idcollection` with a higher price that needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you a lot. In this wat is much easier to store the prices history

Comment: @LeonardoCarlassare If my answer has solved your question, could you please set it as accepted? :) Thanks